# Android SQLite Content Provider query (searchable)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a custom search provider that looks as follows:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hint="hint"
android:label="label"
android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.path_to_provider"
android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.cypher.path_to_provider/table_name"
android:searchSuggestSelection="word LIKE ? || '%' OR word LIKE '% ' || ? || '%'" />
```

When independentally tested, each side of the `OR` in my search suggestion works fine. When I use the OR for some reason, the query does not work.  Is there something wrong with my query? My goal is to have the search "cat" be matched for "catastrophic" and "look at the cats"

Here is my `ContentProvider` query

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = searchHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    return sqLiteDatabase.query("table_name",
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null);
}
```

Comment: Try putting the whole expression in parentheses.

Comment: do you need the whole stuff with ContentProvider, Searchable etc? do you want just to use a private SearchView in your app or is it a part of a "system search" ?

Comment: In what way is your query not working? Are you getting an error, or just 0 results?

Comment: (Still working on the assumption that you're getting an error) You should post your exception stacktrace, so that future searchers can have an easier time verifying that their problem matches yours. Also, may I suggest that you change the question title to "Android searchSuggestionSelection error with multiple placeholders"? If that truly fits your problem, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

The query syntax looks fine, at least, and I seem to get reasonable results:

```
tmp$ sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table words (word VARCHAR(20));
sqlite> insert into words VALUES ("catastrophic");
sqlite> insert into words VALUES ("look at the cats");
sqlite> insert into words VALUES ("uncatty");
sqlite> SELECT * FROM words;
catastrophic
look at the cats
uncatty
sqlite> SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE 'cat' || '%' OR word LIKE '% ' || 'cat' || '%';
catastrophic
look at the cats
```

(I manually substituted in 'cat' for your question marks, since I was running in the sqlite3 CLI.)

You didn't specify in which way your query isn't working. If you're getting an error: could it be that you're not supplying enough selectionArgs? When you have two question marks, your selectionArgs array must be two elements (in this case, both elements would contain the same value). You could also [use ?1 in both places instead of just ?](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam), like so:

```
word LIKE ?1 || '%' OR word LIKE '% ' || ?1 || '%'
```

That will make both the placeholders use the first selection arg (and therefore only require one selection arg).

I hope I guessed your problem correctly. :)

*EDIT:* Ah, I now realize that you don't control the selectionArgs parameter when executing the query, but rather, it comes from the framework. Then yeah, the framework probably only sends one arg, so your multiple placeholders are causing problems. In that case, using ?1 instead of just ? should definitely be the way to go -- your query will then only require one selection arg.